# ListPlot PlotRange Ignored with all Missing or empty data

Tags: plotting, bugs, grid-lines

I have a function that uses `ListPlot` to draw a custom plot.  When a data value is not applicable I pass in `Missing` to prevent `ListPlot` and its `Prolog` option from displaying the point the function will derive from it.

The issue is that there can be sets of data where all of the values are not applicable.  If the set of data has 4 values then, as a minimal example, the function will derive the following list for `ListPlot`.

```
d = {{1, Missing[]}, {2, Missing[]}, {3, Missing[]}, {4, Missing[]}};
```

The function has lots of custom formatting but I can illustrate the issue just with the `GridLines` and `PlotRange` options.

```
ListPlot[d, GridLines -> {Range[Length@d], None}, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, Length@d + .5}, {.3, 3.7}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The issue is that the plot range is completely off.  It is only going from zero to 1 on both axes even though it has been explicitly given ranges for both.  The issue also exists with `d = {}`.

I can work around this by using `-1` or something out of plot range for `Missing` but that will mess up the `Prolog` code.

I would expect `ListPlot` to plot the `PlotRange` no matter the data given to it.  Am I missing something or is this a bug?
*Win 7 Pro Mma 10.0.1*

Confirmed bug: Have to figure out the case number as I am getting a couple of confirms at the moment but all on the same case number. It is one of these but three where responded with separate emails all from one case number so I can't tell which one it is. [CASE:3780234] [CASE:3780235] [CASE:3780239]

Comment: You can do : `Show[yourPlot, PlotRange -> {{.5, Length@d + .5}, {.3, 3.7}}]`

Comment: @andre  That is a good workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe most if not all of the plotting functions ignore plot ranges settings when drawing an empty plot. They seem to revert to a canned viewport. In  2D situations this seems to be the unit square.

Comment: @m_goldberg `Graphics[{},PlotRange-> ...]` works.

Comment: @andre. `Graphics` has different behavior than the `Plot...` family of function, which were the ones I was referring to.

Comment: adding a point out of range is another workaround, even `ListPlot[{d, {Infinity, 0}},..  PlotRange -> {..}]`

Comment: Simplest example is: `ListPlot[{{}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-5, 5}}]` which ignores `PlotRange`. I think it was introduced with v11, as before that my plotting method worked early 2016.